# My SELECT function is searching for a column and not the data in the column. How can I make it search the data?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

When I pass the variable into the l_name.get() variable I am expecting a return from a match in the db. Which then enables the user to identify if a person exists in the dataset already.

When I run the search (from tKinterGUI) I get the following error:

```
*line 35, in search
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE last_name="  + l_name.get())
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Mustang*
```

(Mustang being the search term)

This is the table which was created in SQLite3:

```
c.execute(""" CREATE TABLE addresses (
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    address text,
    city text,
    state text,
    postcode integer)""")
```

Here is the function:

```
def search():
#connect to database from within function
conn = sqlite3.Connection('address_book.db')
#create a cursor from within function
c = conn.cursor()

#Search function in SQL
c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE last_name="  +         l_name.get())
records = c.fetchall()
print_records=""
#this loop will print selected items
for record in records:
        print_records += str(record[0])+ " " + str(record[1]) + "\t" + str(record[2]) + "\n"

#commit changes
conn.commit()
#close connection
conn.close()
#clear text boxes

#query lbl part of the function to display results
query_lbl=Label(root, text=print_records)
query_lbl.grid(row=15,column=0, columnspan=2)
```

I have tested the variable and it is functioning, I have been able to search by oid with the same code, replacing "last_name" with "oid".
I am at a loss. (also quite new to this so please be gentle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of `l_name` is "Mustang", then the final SQL will be:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE last_name=Mustang
```

So the WHERE condition will be comparing two columns: `last_name` and `Mustang`.  What you need is to *quote* the content of `l_name`:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE last_name="Mustang"
```

It is better to use *placeholder* instead:

```py
c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE last_name = ?", (l_name.get(),))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. entering the search term ie, "Mustang" directly into the code does work, and I get the desired return. I need it to be dependent on the conent of the l_name entry. I dont understand why it works if I enter the term directly, and not work when entered using .get()

Answer (score 1):

I needed to pass the .get() function of tKinter into a variable as an argument after the placeholder.

```
x = l_name.get()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE last_name=?",(x,))
```

The function now works as planned and returns data matching the input from the user.